# Where can I set the timeout limit for Sensenet admin users?

Tags: logout, sensenet

I've found an [article](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Common_configurations#Timeout_values) about the timeout, but I don't know which paramteter should be set to log me out after 10 minutes inactivity from the portal (by default it logs me out after 30 minutes). Where can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the session timeout in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <sessionState timeout="10" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> The above config fragment is just an example, please be aware that in your web.config there may be additional attributes on the *sessionState* node.

Please also make sure that the *Idle Timeout* of the app pool in IIS is set to 0 (meaning infinite, this is the recommended value), or to a huge amount so that the app pool does not recycle after a short period of idle time.

Answer (score -1):

It appears to be in IIS on the application pool of the website. You can set it on Process Model Idle Time-Out as [this article](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Configuration_for_Production_Environment_-_version_6.5) states.

Comment: The IIS idle timeout setting is about not allowing the app pool to stop. The recommended setting for sensenet is 0, meaning never let the process shut down. The question is about user sessions.